# ImageButton getting error

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm trying to add a imagebutton on my application but when I try to run it, I'm getting this error:

```
03-21 14:57:41.936: E/AndroidRuntime(794): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.facilit.target.app.android/br.com.facilit.target.app.android.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
```

My XML code:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnEntrar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtFieldSenha"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtFieldSenha"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@style/AppTheme"
            android:contentDescription="@string/btn_entrar_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/login_btn_entrar" />
```

JAVA CODE:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton btnEntrar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnEntrar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnEntrar);

        final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFieldLogin);
        final EditText token = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFieldSenha);

        btnEntrar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d(Constants.LOGIN_ACTIVITY, email.getText().toString().trim());
                Log.d(Constants.LOGIN_ACTIVITY, token.getText().toString().trim());

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Clean your project and then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to use

```
 android:background="@style/AppTheme"
```

But your editor should point out your wrong error in the XML exactly.. try a clean and build if it doesn't.

Comment: If I don't use it, the button comes with a border. I cleaned it, but the problem persists

Answer (score -1):

You are using **@+id** to **layout_alignRight** and **layout_below**.

Try removing the **+**.
It should look like this

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnEntrar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/txtFieldSenha"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtFieldSenha"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@style/AppTheme"
            android:contentDescription="@string/btn_entrar_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/login_btn_entrar" />
```

Comment: @Stefan The + signal is for creating new id. If you are doing a reference to another view, why would you use the +? Explain to me, please

Comment: If you use android:layout_below="@id/txtFieldSenha" , and you have that txtFieldSenha defined below your ImageButton, it will crash as there is no such id yet. Using the + will prevent this.

Comment: Ohh ok. I thought this would cause troubles, because it would try to add 3 times the same ID in the same layout. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: No, basically it just skips the references, and comes back to it later again when the whole layout is initiated. I'm not sure if there is a little performance trade-off, it does sound like it is a little extra work. In my opinion probably not enough though to choose it above usability of your code. Like this you and no-one else has to worry about this when changing your layout.